# How to use a "cell" as input for a Julia function

Tags: julia

I am trying to use a cell as input for a Julia function as follows

`U    = cell(2)
U[1] = zeros(3,3)
U[2] = zeros(3,3)`

`function f_test{S<:AbstractFloat}(U::Array{S})
a = zero(S) 
return a
end`

I do: `f_test(U)` and I got

`LoadError: MethodError:`f_test`has no method matching f_test(::Array{Any,1})
while loading In[391], in expression starting on line 10`

Of course it works when `f_test(U[1])`

Any ideas ?

Comment: `Array{Any}` (the type of the `cell` vector) does not match the parametric pattern: `Any <: AbstractFloat` is `false`

Comment: Why are you using cell? This is almost always a bad idea,  since it gives Julia no information about type. In your case you have a vector of two objects, each of which have the same type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

What if I have

`U    = cell(2)

U[1] = zeros(3,1)

U[2] = zeros(3,3)`

In this case, they do not have the same type...

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Actually, I need a U containing Matrices of different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia, the size of a matrix is not part of its type. So you don't need `cell` here. In fact, this works fine:

```
U = Matrix{Float64}[zeros(3, 3), zeros(3, 1)]
```

Here we create an `Vector` of `Matrix{Float64}`. `Matrix{Float64}` is a typealias for `Array{Float64,2}`, which means "two-dimensional array of `Float64`. The type of `U` is `Array{Array{Float64,2},1}`; that is, it's a vector (one dimensional array) of matrices (two-dimensional arrays) of `Float64`. Unusual, but perfectly valid.

But a vector of arrays is not the same as a single array, so your function `f_test` won't work on `U`. What you seem to want is a *vectorized* version of `f_test` that applies the function to all matrices of the vector, and gives back a vector containing each result. This is how functions like `sin` currently work in Julia (though that may change in the future), so it can be surprising that functions do not do this automatically.

What I would recommend is to explicitly `map` the function across your array:

```
map(f_test, U)  # result: [0.0, 0.0]
```

which is most clear. If you must have the function vectorized, you can define the additional method itself:

```
julia> f_test{S<:Matrix}(U::Vector{S}) = map(f_test, U)
f_test (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f_test(U)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
```

but I would not recommend that approach.